# Using fiddler to capture html when no proxy support in browser

Tags: html, webview, proxy, fiddler, chromium

I'm using the webview tag in chromium and I want to capture the html requests.  Unfortunately webview does not support proxies.  Is there any way I can just do a normal http request to fiddler at localhost:8888 and somehow put the real destination in the URL? Maybe something like `http://localhost:8888?url=google.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on which `Chromium` you're using, but generally I'd expect that it should adopt the OS proxy settings, and if it doesn't, that's a bug that should get filed.

Yes, you can send Web Requests directly to Fiddler using the technique you describe, but the cookies and security permissions aren't likely to work correctly.

Comment: `I'm not clear on which Chromium`: it's the one built into atom/shell. `that's a bug that should get filed.`: It has been for a long time but google is ignoring it.  `you can send Web Requests directly to Fiddler using the technique you describe`: where can I find the URL format?

Comment: @mark-Hahn: Use any format you want. Then you write script inside OnBeforeRequest to "Fix up" the URL based on the format you decided upon.

Comment: This: https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-there-any-proxy-settings/710/22 suggests that there's a way to manually update a config file for the app to point a the proxy.

Comment: `apm config set https-proxy http://localhost:8888` from that post worked for me in windows.

Comment: One more question.  You said `Then you write script inside OnBeforeRequest`.  Where is this script supposed to go?  Inside fiddler?